# Как изменить шрифт в файле, используя c++?

Tags: c++, шрифты, ms-word

Это программа которая записывает в Word десять слов. Но после выполнения, слова записаны стандартном шрифтом, в стандартом размере, цвете и т.д. Можно ли как-то изменить шрифт, размер и цвет слов. Вот код:

```
#include<windows.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    ofstream a;
    a.open("29 February 2020 (Saturday).doc");
    if (a.is_open()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            string word;
            cin >> word;
            a << word << ", " << endl;
        }
        a.close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Эта программа создает обычный текстовый файл, а не документ MS Word. То что Word этот файл отображает - случайность.

Решить задачу малой кровью можно используя формат RTF (Rich Text Format). Необходимо разобраться как в нем изменяется шрифт, и добавить соответствующие `a << ...` в код программы.